# Why has the Eclipse Debugger/Emulator disconnected from my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

My app is no longer starting up automatically when I F11 it in Eclipse; the Emulator starts up, but I then have to go and find my app among the applications list/array to invoke it.

Then, when I get to the place in my app where I've set a breakpoint, instead of hitting the breakpoint (Eclipse is not even going into Debug Perspective), my app suddenly "expires" and the Emulator pops up the dialog:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Sorry!

The application FifeOrTheDinosaur (process.com.aXX3AndSpace.FifeOrTheDinosaur_Package) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Force close

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

But then when I click "Force Close," that dialog goes away, and my app starts up again, from its opening Activity...?!?

It's almost as if my app is not the one being debugged by Eclipse -- Eclipse has lost its connection to it or...???

And every time it crashed, I hit the "Force Close" button, whereupon my app starts up all over again. What could have disconnected my app from the Debugging system, so that it:
1) Doesn't run automatically when I run it; rather, I have to "force" it to start up, and when it enters a breakpoint, Eclipse's Debug Perspective is not invoked
2) Continually starts up my app *after* it has failed...???
I put a breakpoint on a button click handler prior to that one that is working fine, and it does not drop me into the Eclipse debugger, either...???

Update:
The console says:

1) ] Failed to install .apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
2) Launch canceled!

Updated 3/30/2012:

If I run the app from Eclipse and immediately shut it down just as the Emulator is starting to initialize, it flashes up three "command window"-type screens, one right after the other, too fast to read what text they contain. Normally the Emulator window simply goes away, so I don't know if this is a clue for anybody as to what might be happening...

Comment: @edthethird: I've restarted my entire system (computer, then Eclipse, then the Android project). I updated my post to give a little more detail about something that's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like the normal behavior of android Apps. If one activity crashes you can still go back to the activity the App started with. And if the breakpoints aren't hit then the error might occure before the code line you want to stop at. 
Maybe you could set a breakpoint before you change the activity and then debug from there on.
You could also provide your Log output. Errors like that can always happen if you forgot to declare permissions or activities in your Android Manifest.